# Default date parameter in postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass todays date as a default date parameter into a postgres stored procedure?

My attempt so far is:

```
create or replace procedure my_schema.my_procedure(InputDate date DEFAULT now())
as $$

begin 
    raise notice 'Input Date: %', InputDate;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

and I am getting this error

```
Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7f2d8629ad8527d049892ca63c5ed820)

Comment: "NOTICE:  Input Date: 2022-02-17", works fine